# issue Initializing SimpleMembership in filter class

Tags: c#, asp.net, simplemembership

I am trying to initialize attribute class but for some reason I am struggling with results.

I have created MVC4 "Basic" project template in visual studio 2012. I have created folder with name Filters in my project and create class InitializeSimpleMembership.cs. I have Home controller and associated view and finally I am calling [InitializeSimpleMembership] in home controller class but no result. Application is not generating required tables. (note: I Have created database before)

I am trying to initialize SimpleMemberShip with least code so that I can understand and make it complex along it grows.

### In Filter folder

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebMatrix.WebData;
using SimpleLogin_System_04.Models;

namespace SimpleLogin_System_04.Filters
 {
  public class InitializeSimpleMembership : ActionFilterAttribute
  {
    private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
    {
        public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
        { 
          try
            {                  
              WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, ex);
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

### HomeController

```
namespace SimpleLogin_System_04.Controllers
 {
[InitializeSimpleMembership]
public class HomeController : Controller
{    
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
}
```

### Web.config ; Connection String

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=dd3;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\dd3.mdf" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not see anything that invokes the constructor for **SimpleMembershipInitializer**, which has the code for initializing the database.  Why not just put that code in the default constructor for **InitializeSimpleMembership**.

I would recommend just putting the initialization in the Global.asax **Application_Start** method instead of using a filter class since you are putting it in the **HomeController**.  The reason the MVC 4 Internet template uses a filter on the **AccountController** is for lazy loading security only when security is being used. If you always want it initialized just use Global.asax. There is a good description on [initialization of **SimpleMembership** in this article](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/01/seeding-customizing-aspnet-mvc.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes i have realized I wasn't calling the constructor. I want carry on using filter namespace because eventually I will add lazy loading. is just for time being trying to break things into smallest parts so that i can understand the security behavior.

plus i was missing few implementation as well... but got system running now! here i have approach to problem.

### Filters Folder

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebMatrix.WebData;
using SimpleLogin_System_04.Models;

namespace SimpleLogin_System_04.Filters
{
public class InitializeSimpleMembership : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public InitializeSimpleMembership()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
            {
                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

}

### webconfig

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=DB4;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\DB4.mdf" />
</connectionStrings>

<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
  </providers>
</membership>

<roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

### Account Controller class

```
[Authorize]
[InitializeSimpleMembership]
public class AccountController : Controller
```

and database i have created before the codes run because i don't want system to create one if it can't find one. although it is creating table in simple membership database connection initializing stage..